# onEvent() is not being called?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-tabbed-activity

I am passing data from `AsyncTask` to a fragment of tabbed activity. Why `onEvent()` of EventBus is not being called?

`BackgroundWorker.java` doInBackground() is called by MainActivity

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String line) {
     userResult =  line.split(" ");
     String result = userResult[0];

     if(result.equals("Success")){
       CustomMessageEvent event = new CustomMessageEvent();
       event.setCustomMessage(line);
       Intent intent = new Intent(context,TabActivity.class);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(intent);
       EventBus.getDefault().post(event);
     }
   }
}
```

`ProfileTab.java` This file is a fragment of tabbed activity. Is there anything that should be done in tabbed activity or should doInBackground must be called again.

```
public class ProfileTab extends Fragment {

  public TextView t1;
  private View rootView;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);

    t1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: ");

    return rootView;
  }

  @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.ASYNC)
  public void onEventAsync(CustomMessageEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: ");
    t1.setText(event.getCustomMessage());
  }

}
```

Tried LocalBroadcastManager and the result was same, `onReceive()` was not called. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start Activity in your `onPostExecute`, I suggest pass data by intent, not events - it is simpler.
Your subscribed method isn't called, because event is posted before you register -  use `postSticky` instead of `post`, and you will get an event.

I assume, you want to pass `line` (`String`). So construct intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,TabActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("LINE", line);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Than, in your `TabActivity` in onCreate read passed value:

```
String line = getIntent().getStringExtra("LINE", "");
```

Comment: As I suggest, use intent, not `EventBus` there.

Comment: How to use `postSticky` without `EventBus`. Can you please give the code to use intent? I'm a beginner to Android.

Comment: It helped. I then passed the data from tabbed activity to fragment using bundle.

Comment: That is the correct way. `EventBus` is helpful and nice library, but not everywhere.